# Not able to checkout in svn in ubuntu

Tags: svn

I am using terminal to checkout from  Svn repository but showing this error

```
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xp-dev.com/...'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/...' forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a username using

```
svn co --username your_name https://svn.server.com/repository/trunk
```

and the password should be prompted afterwards.

However, it's not necessary to specify the username, svn is going to prompt you anyway.

This and more information can be found either in the documentation of svn or using a simple command:

```
svn help checkout
```

Comment: you have to provide your username and password for the svn/xp-dev